# send php http request and store a link on the page as variable

Tags: php, http

Can someone tell me if the following is feasible:

1. Send a variable to a web searchable database (I have been able to accomplish this).
2. The webpage that I am currently directly the users contains the actual link that is helpful to the users. is there a way that I can directly send the user to that link using an http request? That would save the users from having to click on extra link.

Thanks

I think I did not provide enough information.

So currently the search spits out a table with the links as one of the columns. The user can than click on one of these links and then on the following page, they can click on another link to get to the information that they need.

I am hoping to pull that information in the background and replace the first link with the second link. Redirecting is not an option (I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//do redirection in your php file using the header fn and don't show any output before this call 
header('Location: http://redirecturl.com/');
exit;
?>
```

For more information visit [php header fn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: please see above, i cannot redirect as the search returns a table full of url links.

Comment: Then the ideal solution is to join the second redirection link on the first query and instead of showing the first link you can directly show the actual redirection link or clicking on the first link should redirect to the actual redirection link. If you want help with db query then you need to explain your database structure

Comment: That is exactly that I am trying to accomplish. "clicking on the first link should redirect to the actual redirection link." The database consists of drug name and ID. they Drug ID is what is send to the remote server by joining with a webpage string and returns a page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at header function (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php):

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: please see above, i cannot redirect as the search returns a table full of url links.